# Convert string[] to Array

Tags: c#, arrays, type-conversion

I am a little lost in data types at the moment.

In the application I'm building, I have a function that has to run a query, depending on a `Array` of customer ID's.

The data has to be overwritten on a certain condition, with an array formed from the string of ID's.

The problem is that the `Split()` function returns a `string[]`, while my data is a `Array`. I can assign the new values to `data`, like seen below, but then I can't access the data any more.

This is because for a `Array`, I have to use `data.GetValue(i)`, while a `string[]` can only be accessed with `data[i]`.

Stripped down code:

```
internal void GetData(Array data) {

    string ids == "123,456,789";

    if(condition){
        data = (Array) ids.Split(',').ToArray(); // Trying to convert it to a Array, can't figure it out...
    }

    // Accessing the data at index `i`
    data.GetValue(i); // Default case, works when the condition is false
    data[i];          //     This only works when the condition is true
}
```

So, my question is, is there a way for me to save my split string to a `Array` instead of a `string[]`?

---

Full code:

```
internal M.RequestCustomQueryResultsList GetData(Array data) {
    M.RequestCustomQueryResultsList result = new M.RequestCustomQueryResultsList();
    result.CustomQueryResults = new List<CustomQueryResult>();

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

    conn.Open();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    cmd.CommandText = queriesQuery; // StacOverflow: A query to obtain some queries

    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while(reader.Read()) {
        // For each query
        SqlConnection conn1 = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        conn1.Open();

        /* StackOverflow: The real relevant stuff starts here. */

        String query = reader["Query"].ToString(); // Get the current query

        Match match = Regex.Match(query, @"{((?:\w,?)*)}");

        if(match.Success) { // If the query contains "{0}" or "{123,456,789,etc}"
            string m = match.Groups[1].Value; // get the value in the "{}"
            if(!m.Equals("0")){ // If that value isn't "123,456,etc"
                data = m.Split(','); // Split up the id's into an array.
            }
            for(int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++) { // Loop through the data (Works if m.Equals("0"))
                // Execute the query for every company.
                String q = string.Format(query, data.GetValue(i).ToString()); // Fails
                CustomQueryResult c = new CustomQueryResult();

                c.CustNo = int.Parse(data.GetValue(i).ToString());  // Fails

                // Here I set some more values to c, add c  to `result`, and close all loops / etc.
```

`GetData` is part of called as a `GetCustomQueriesResults` request to a service.

```
public T.RequestCustomQueryResultsList GetCustomQueriesResults(Array data) {
    var CustomQueriesResultsList = new S.CustomQueriesResultsList(data);
    return CustomQueriesResultsList.GetData(data);
}
```

I call the service from JavaScript, like this:

```
repo.GetCustomQueriesResults([123,456,789]);
```

The repo builds a ajax request that uses `JSON.stringify(data)` as `data` parameter.

Comment: A `string[]` is already an `Array`...

Comment: @MarcGravell: But I can't access it with `.GetValue(i);` (Or the Array I receive with `[i]`), that's the problem. I'm not that familiar with the types, yet, in C#... That also makes me think there's a difference between a `Array` and a `string[]`

Comment: why do you say you can't access it? That is fine.

Comment: Replace `GetValue(i)` with `GetValue(1)` and see what happens........(you get `456`)

Comment: Do you have any error message ?

Comment: Could the person that downvoted me please tell me why? If I made a mistake, I'd like to learn from it.

Answer (score 5):

A `string[]` is already an `Array` (because each concrete array type derived from `Array`) - and `Split` already gives a `string[]`, so you don't need to call `ToArray` on the result.

So this:

```
data = (Array) ids.Split(',').ToArray();
```

can just be:

```
data = ids.Split(',');
```

The result *is* an array, so there's no other work to do.

Note that changing the value of `data` will *not* change the caller's array at all, if that's what's going wrong. You should read my [article on parameter passing](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html) to find out more about that side of things.

EDIT: Now that we can see your code, I believe the problem has very little to do with arrays. It's this:

```
String q = string.Format(query, data.GetValue(i).ToString()); // Fails
```

I *strongly* suspect that your query contains something like `{1}` which is trying to *format* using an argument which isn't present.

It should be easy to validate this - just separate out the parts:

```
String value = data.GetValue(i).ToString();
String q = string.Format(query, value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just assign it:

```
data = ids.Split(',');
```

you don't need the cast, and you don't need the `ToArray`.

Answer (score 0):

`GetValue` works fine in both cases (see below LinqPad snippet). This is to be expected since `Array` is the base class of all arrays, so `GetValue` is inherited.
You may be doing something wrong somewhere else.

```
void Main()
{
    Array myArr = Array.CreateInstance( typeof(String),1);
    myArr.SetValue("a",0);
    GetData(myArr,true); // condition is true, use the split. Outputs "123"
    GetData(myArr,false); // use the array we pass to the method. Outputs "a"   
}

void GetData(Array data, bool condition) {

    string ids = "123,456,789";

    if(condition) 
    {
        data = ids.Split(','); 
    }
    Console.WriteLine(data.GetValue(0)); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the [ArrayType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.aspx) does not declare any indexer. That's why you can not use the [] on an object of type Array.

Saying that I can't undestrand from where came the hability to call an indexer on Split() result.

But you can replace

```
GetData(Array data)
```

by

```
GetData(Object[] data)
```

Which in my mind has the same meaning.